# Me actualiza todos los registros de las pivotes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, base-de-datos, eloquent

En Laravel 5.4 estoy intentando guardar el contenido de una relación N:M en una la pivote , el problema que tengo es que me actualiza todos los registros que estan relacionados con ese id, es como si hiciera un update con el where del id del alumno .

El código :

```
$alumnos = Alumnos::obtenerAlumnosAsignaturas();
foreach($alumnos as $alumno){
 if($alumno->pivot->asignatura == null){
  $alumno->pivot->asignatura = 0;
  $alumno->pivot->save();
 }
}
```

Las dos tablas

```
| id | alumno| |id|asignaturas |
|----|-------| |--|------------|
| 1  | Juan  | | 1| Matemáticas|
| 2  | Pepe  | | 2| Lengua     |
| 3  | Luis  | | 3| Inglés     |
|----|-------| |--|------------|
```

Pivote

```
| id | asignatura_id | alumno_id |
|----|---------------|-----------|
| 1  | 1             | 1         |
| 1  | 1             | 2         |
| 3  | 3             | 3         |
```

Despues de ejecutar el código pasa a :

```
| id | asignatura_id | alumno_id |
|----|---------------|-----------|
| 1  | 1             | 0         |
| 2  | 1             | 0         |
| 3  | 3             | 3         |
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar un poco más de código / contexto? y contarnos también que versión exacta de Laravel usas

Comment: ya he especificado.

Comment: ¿cómo puedes tener dos id = 1 en la tabla pivote? No es en teoría un autoincrementable? Podrías mostrarnos las migraciones y los modelos también.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado.

```
// Obtenemos todos los alumnos con sus corrrespondientes asignaturas
$alumnos = Alumnos::obtenerAlumnosAsignaturas();
// Los recorremos
foreach($alumnos as $alumno){
 // Si encontramos un registro del alumno de su asignatura a null 
 if($alumno->pviot->asignatura == null){
  // Accedo a la pivote , por medio de mi modelo en la N:M
  $pivote = AlumnosAsignaturas::findOrFail($alumno->pivot->id);
  $pivote->asignatura = 0;
  $pivote->save();
 }
}
```

Ahora lo explico :

Lo que hice fue crear un modelo para la tabla pivote que sale de la N:M , de alumnos y asignaturas , porque en una asignaturas puede haber más de un alumno y un alumno puede pertenecer a más de una asignatura , más que se puede dar el caso de que pueda no cubrirse el campo , donde se pondría a null , lo que a su vez es un problema de diseño de la base de datos.

Modelos :

```
Alumnos -------> AlumnosAsignaturas <------- Asignaturas
```

Espero que esto ayude a futuras personas que tengan este error.
No pongáis negativos por no comprender la pregunta. 
Se agradecería.